# É possível adicionar um comportamento de overflow com scroll somente no tbody de uma table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

É possível adicionar um comportamento de ***overflow*** com ***scroll*** somente no ***tbody*** de uma ***table*** e ainda assim não ter que setar tamanhos fixos em ***pixels***, sem precisar fazer uma separação do cabeçalho das colunas com o corpo, como é visto nos *plugins* que disponibilizam *grids*?

css para o overflow:

```html
table.grid tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

tabela:

```html
<table class='grid'>
    <thead> ... <thead>

    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>

    <tfoot> ... </tfoot>
</table>
```

A intenção é que, mesmo uma tabela tendo registros que ultrapassam o limite da área na qual ela está alocada, que ela não sobreponha esse limite, mas que os registros sejam navegáveis por meio da barra de rolagem, como em grids de sistemas desktop, e quem sabe tentar adaptá-la para ser responsivel.

---

## EDIÇÃO

Segue exemplo de como apenas adicionar o *css* de ***overflow*** ao ***tbody*** não funciona:

[image: exemplo do funcionamento do overflow no tbody da table]

Como podem ver na imagem, a ***table*** está inserida em uma ***div*** que possui um tamanho **fixo de 200px de altura**. Porém a *table* continua ultrapassando esse limite.

Comment: Boa pergunta, a tempos atrás já perdi algum tempo tentando algo do tipo em uma tabela que utilizava, `thead`, `tbody` e `tfoot`, mas não obtive sucesso e acabei tendo que criar os _headers_ o _body_ e o _footer_ da tabela em `table` separados, que visualmente pareçam o mesmo, mas se obtiver sucesso, dou um _rollback_ em meu projeto. +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É possível, mas a solução é meio convoluta por causa do comportamento dos elementos relacionados ao elemento `<TABLE>`.

Por padrão, `tbody` possui a propriedade `display:row-group`. Isso permite aos navegadores manter o alinhamento entre células na mesma coluna em partes diferentes da tabela (`thead`, `tbody` e `tfoot`).

Para permitir *overflow*, você vai precisar alterar a propriedade `display` dos elementos `thead`, `tbody` e `tfoot` para `block`. Porém, isso cria um problema: você perde o alinhamento entre as células do cabeçalho, corpo e rodapé.

Como *workaround*, você irá precisar coordenar o tamanho das células via JavaScript ou JQuery.

[Existe uma resposta no Stack Overflow original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody) que cobre exatamente este comportamento. A seguir, a tradução dos pontos importantes:

> Os navegadores exibem os elementos thead e tbody como row-group (
>   *table-header-group* e *table-row-group*) por padrão.
>
> Uma vez que alteramos isso, os elementos `tr` não preenchem todo o
>   espaço de seu container.

### CSS

```
thead, tbody { display: block; }

tbody {
    height: 100px;       
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Exibe a barra de rolamento vertical     */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Esconde a barra de rolamento horizontal */
}
```

### JQuery

```
// Mude o seletor 'table' de acordo com sua necessidade.
var $table = $('table'),
    $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
    colWidth;

// Obtém o array de largura de colunas dentro de tbody
colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
}).get();

// Ajusta o tamanho das colunas no cabeçalho
$table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
});
```

Um Fiddler com exemplo deste processo (incluindo rodapé) [pode ser visto aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mh4vz5f5/).
Uma versão que respeita o tamanho do container [pode ser vista aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mh4vz5f5/1/).

Comment: @TiagoSilva Uma versão respeitando o espaço do container: http://jsfiddle.net/mh4vz5f5/1/

Comment: @TiagoSilva, sim, sim, estava analisando a resposta do OnoSendai, e é possível, com algumas limitações, mas é melhor que a minha solução/gambiarra. Na época desisti quando fui ver como [esse do PrimeFaces/JSF/Java](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml) era feito e verifiquei que era com 3 tabelas, então concluir que seria a unica forma. Mas que bom que há solução e simples pois é um problema redimensionamento de colunas, se é 3 tabelas, tem que ficar fazendo script para manter as colunas sempre no mesmo tamanho. _Go! Go! Rollback Project_. hehe

Answer (score 0):

É possivel colocar o overflow somente no tbody

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Campo1</td>
            <td>Campo 2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>row1</td><td>row1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>row2</td><td>row2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>row3</td><td>row3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>row4</td><td>row4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>row4</td><td>row4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>row4</td><td>row4</td></tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
tbody {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
td {
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/2/

Comment: Adicionei o Fiddle. E funciona no exemplo