# Fixar primeira linha tabela

Tags: css, table

Preciso fixar a primeira linha da minha tabela sempre no topo da página.
Já li várias perguntas sobre esse mesmo problema, mas não consegui resolver...

O meu código:

```
<table border="2px">

 <tr bgcolor="0099FF" id="topo">
      <th> ID </th>
      <th> Acertos Humanas </th>
      <th> Nota humanas </th>
      <th> Acertos Naturezas </th>
      <th> Nota Naturezas </th>
      <th> Acertos Linguagens </th>
      <th> Nota Linguagens </th>
      <th> Acertos Matematica </th>
      <th> Nota Matematica </th>
      <th> Soma acertos </th>
      <th> Soma notas </th>
      <th> Soma acertos(2) </th>
      <th> Redacao </th>
      <th> Media sem redacao </th>
      <th> Media com redacao </th>
 </tr>


<?php 

$tudo = file('notas.txt');

for ($l=0; $l<90; $l++) {

    $cada_item[$l] = explode (" ", $tudo[$l]);

    $idd = $l+1;

    $cor = $l%2 !=0 ? "#D0D0D0" : "white"; 

    echo '<tr bgcolor="'.$cor.'"><td>'. $idd ."</td>";

      for ($i=0; $i<14; $i++) {
          echo "<td>". $cada_item[$l][$i] ."</td>";
      }

    echo "</tr>";
}

?>

</table>
```

Eu tentei uma série de coisas, mas preferi tirar para não prejudicar o código.
Achei que era só pegar o primeiro `tr` no css e colocar `position:fixed`.
E depois outra div envolta dos outros `trs`, ou seja, envolta das tags do php.
Mas o maior problema é que a largura de cada célula da tabela não segue a largura das células `th` e aí fica tudo torto porque a largura da tabela fica menor que a da primeira linha...
Eu quero fazer isso com css (aceito solução com javascript em segundo caso, mas sem jquery, por favor) Valeu!

Comment: Viu esta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32304/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-adicionar-um-comportamento-de-overflow-com-scroll-somente-no-tbody-de

Comment: Não entendi qual a solução?! Aqui não funciona. O que acontece é que quando eu coloco a primeira linha fixa, o resto fica comprimido. E não adianta mexer no resto via css. Não muda nada na prática.

Comment: Essa tabela ocupará toda a página ou ela estará dentro de um elemento?

Comment: Toda página, renan.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, basta usar o `position:fixed` e, defina uma largura fixa para as células.

E você utilizou a repetição em php para definir as cores de cada linha. Tambem pode ser feito atráves do css3 com o seletor `nth-child`

```css
table {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    table-layout: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width:500px;
}

tr:first-child {
    background: #0099FF;
    position:fixed;
}

th, td {
    width:25%;
}

tr:not(:first-child):nth-child(odd) {
    background:#D0D0D0
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Acertos Humanas</th>
        <th>Notas Humanas</th>
        <th>Acertos Naturezas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7.0</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `position:fixed` não posicionará o restante da tabela corretamente.

Comment: Está torto e o loop ali gera 90 linhas, a tabela tem scrool.

Comment: O que eu nunca vi foi uma tabela com posição fixa, mas se vc quer essa é a forma. O que vc pode fazer é estilizar e ajustar a sua maneira.

Answer (score 2):

Uma abordagem mais atual seria usando `position:sticky` nas `<th>`. Isso faz com que essa parte da tabela permaneça fixa no lugar enquanto o resto do conteúdo faz o *scroll* normalmente.

Segue um exemplo básico usando essa propriedade:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 250px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

**OBS:** Vc pode consultar o suporte dos browsers ao `position:sticky` aqui, mas já adianto que não funciona no IE: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Answer (score 1):

Cara acho que dá sim. Dá uma olhada nesse jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

Você precisa usar a tag `thead` pra isso:

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

E agora o HTML:

```
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellpadding</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellspacing</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>frame</td>
          <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rules</td>
          <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>summary</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>width</td>
          <td>pixels, %</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Esse código corta 2 ths da minha tabela.

Comment: Consegui fazer parcialmente. Numa resolução fixa tá funcionando. Para diferentes resoluções corta colunas da tabela

Comment: @ZebraDoMal Você não pode usar nenhum tipo de JS, Bootstrap ou Foundation Zurb né? O Bootstrap e o Foundation tem ótimas formas de fazer tabelas responsivas.

Comment: Você poderia baixar o SASS/LESS deles, somente a parte que interessa, e usá-las. Mas daí teria que usar em conjunto com o sistema de Grid deles para ficar bem legal mesmo.