# Thead absolute com scrum lateral

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Olá, estou com um problema em uma tabela que é muito extensa na horizontal e vertical. Preciso que os títulos acompanhem os dados até o final na rolagem vertical e horizontal e também preciso que os títulos acompanhem os dados na rolagem fora da div da tabela.

Encontrei algo parecido aqui no fórum, porém não permite a rolagem fora da Div da tabela. segue o link: http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/X2Kmd/1/

Quem puder ajudar agradeço muito..

Comment: Não entendi essa parte "preciso que os títulos acompanhem os dados na rolagem fora da div da tabela." e qual o problema do exemplo do link, por que ele não te atende?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Tentarei ser mais claro. No exemplo que mandei, o thead da table fica parado junto com o view port e o que se move na rolagem horizontal e vertical  é o tbody.  Eu preciso que haja uma rolagem fora do tbody.

Comment: Olha esse exemplo usando Bootstrap veja se é isso que precisa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329027/thead-com-topo-fixo-table/329048#329048 aqui tem outro modelo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44546/fixar-primeira-linha-tabela/329101#329101

Comment: É quase isso mais. Eu preciso que a barra de rolagem da direita também se movimente e que o thead continue acompanhando os dados.

Comment: Vc tem algum exemplo de alguma tabela que funcione do jeito que vc quer? Tem algum link de exemplo

Comment: Gostaria muito mais anda não consegui encontrar.

Comment: O mais próximo que encontrei foi este plugin : https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o meu problema utilizando este pluguin jquery: https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Freeze-Table-Thead-At-Top-jQuery.html